# R: ICC (psych) function with multilevel organization

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, icc, reliability

I am trying to apply the ICC(2,k)function to assess the reliability of a new machine. Any help is appreciated!

- There was only 1 rater throughout the experiment
- 14 people were scanned monocularly
- They were scanned 3 times per session (3 traces/eye)
- They came back 3 times in the same day (9 traces/eye in a day)
- They came back 3 days in the same week (27 traces/eye in a week)

[image]

The ICC function internally uses `lmer` to fit a random effects model. Specifically, it fits the model lmer(y~1 + (1|samples) + (1|repeats)). When I run the ICC code for the log values of my outcome variable, I get the following output:

[image]

I interpret the number of judges as the number of repeats (3 traces per session). However, it is treating each row as an independent sample/subject (226 total), when many of them belong to the same person, as indicated by the variable `ID`.

I am unsure how to to make the ICC function realize there are 14 people rather than 226 and calculate the ICC accordingly. Should I reformat my data? I am not sure how to do it while conserving the hierarchy.

I will be posting to cross-validated as well. I have been using this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/439502/icc-value-of-0-boundary-singular-fit-interpretation) to guide my thought process.

This is my data:

```
structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L), .Label = c("S01", 
"S02", "S03", "S04", "S05", "S06", "S07", "S08", "S09", "S10", 
"S13", "S15", "S16", "S17"), class = "factor"), eye = c("L", 
"L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", 
"R", "R", "R", "R", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", 
"R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", 
"L", "L", "L", "L", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "L", "L", 
"L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", 
"R", "R", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "R", "R", "R", 
"R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", 
"L", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "L", "L", "L", 
"L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", 
"R", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "R", "R", "R", "R", 
"R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "R", 
"R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", 
"L", "L", "L", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", 
"R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", 
"L", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "L", "L", "L", 
"L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "L", 
"L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", 
"R", "R", "R", "R"), Day = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 
1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 
3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 
1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 
3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 
1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 
2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 
1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 
3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 
2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 
3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
2, 2, 3, 3, 3), Time = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 
1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 
2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 
1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 
3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 
1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 
2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 
3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 
3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 
2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 
1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 
3, 1, 2, 3), Video1 = c(0.087980907, 0.138229468, 0.087265621, 
0.195986087, NA, 0.169965326, 0.087600668, NA, NA, 0.092477223, 
0.091350528, 0.032918043, 0.152168109, 0.099289976, 0.073414486, 
0.55374223, 0.145585337, 0.183976925, 0.036795848, 0.181787784, 
0.056040284, 0.118583723, 0.077361293, 0.102967699, 0.160763961, 
0.124360548, 0.149915938, 0.179175193, 0.071730328, 0.149968128, 
0.153503167, 0.095037811, 0.075409002, 0.174832967, 0.141088859, 
0.038881157, 0.061564117, 0.054163262, 0.046867349, 0.040123011, 
0.054647735, 0.060849565, 0.074817049, 0.047454334, 0.087318019, 
0.039463224, 0.079722026, 0.052817568, 0.021839778, 0.059919709, 
0.090052431, 0.180300519, 0.160604452, 0.287542322, 0.200999919, 
0.20508116, 0.083250047, 0.157708361, 0.284022821, 0.136359313, 
0.086814307, 0.16719986, 0.137407529, 0.102210657, 0.168310974, 
0.161919932, 0.130113124, 0.107775902, 0.054302189, 0.060560227, 
0.053947741, 0.062641303, 0.052143943, 0.071859386, 0.068697917, 
0.074580461, 0.062634558, 0.052877909, 0.045341566, 0.036891534, 
0.0519817, 0.068383676, 0.072422589, 0.065883961, NA, NA, NA, 
0.18704615, 0.064510084, NA, NA, NA, 0.281343398, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.132005827, 0.166076829, 0.156412738, 0.124993123, 
0.153797119, 0.23523115, 0.204244576, 0.179591735, 0.241662374, 
0.206093404, 0.194222736, NA, 0.160341745, 0.228276279, NA, 0.148244217, 
0.267088919, 0.142376066, 0.120874336, 0.116038161, 0.07570081, 
0.092018565, 0.18764035, 0.097570968, 0.275982193, 0.083032991, 
0.076835039, 0.129962405, 0.039216406, 0.092339901, 0.09752681, 
0.164013828, 0.086334678, 0.107876919, 0.126481021, 0.147617556, 
0.082634062, 0.054770826, 0.028749862, 0.143956984, 0.051684409, 
0.221550722, 0.233068936, 0.151027184, 0.162539415, 0.161836479, 
0.164355007, 0.130113218, 0.094768854, 0.12844588, 0.068543029, 
0.065301438, 0.158409656, 0.043416089, 0.088338498, 0.135535504, 
0.104713826, 0.055394193, 0.067243652, 0.101152186, 0.054197084, 
0.090209342, 0.10545278, 0.074863354, 0.100904934, 0.117767968, 
0.095591052, 0.105648135, 0.031272578, 0.288074114, 0.134108567, 
0.239842391, 0.089574413, 0.112689104, 0.113394894, NA, NA, 0.154518739, 
0.324720078, 0.119985361, NA, 0.144774891, NA, NA, 0.453636633, 
0.490269309, NA, 0.082747081, 0.057837022, 0.133037941, NA, 0.165724098, 
0.229381388, 0.209086406, 0.101479891, 0.205932066, 0.234497882, 
0.079760758, 0.181086985, 0.140277599, 0.038782905, 0.127672401, 
0.220278395, 0.218946954, 0.112720006, 0.155244665, 0.171597108, 
0.086627495, 0.04037711, 0.031625864, 0.083406063, 0.044853662, 
0.070224764, 0.074856116, 0.1314991, 0.094837903, 0.062767123, 
0.04305756, 0.020832593, 0.050751347, 0.058208723, 0.114863961, 
0.07299349, 0.065228472, 0.042690128), Video2 = c(0.114125673, 
NA, 0.060309691, 0.164117324, 0.060891372, 0.41365488, 0.018451836, 
0.158369521, NA, 0.098791936, 0.035309485, 0.077134396, NA, 0.062498159, 
0.115475734, 0.08324786, NA, 0.124140619, 0.118365888, 0.117836949, 
0.047061138, 0.087292064, 0.08407374, 0.092185632, 0.090598798, 
0.200259434, 0.113220122, 0.048218976, 0.036608844, 0.118584237, 
0.125454968, 0.101731714, 0.084789024, 0.158389537, 0.210365439, 
0.062385049, 0.065149087, 0.281668702, 0.054592426, 0.046126902, 
0.087065465, 0.072164099, 0.088374659, 0.085297405, 0.048997511, 
0.100124277, 0.040702851, 0.080152996, 0.025137424, 0.078181594, 
0.057469833, 0.247824038, 0.115295019, 0.166448579, 0.137513527, 
0.186291366, 0.115566612, 0.168936072, 0.167011681, 0.197827763, 
0.184426189, 0.139032114, 0.15280477, 0.133926332, 0.165605902, 
0.162007503, 0.078905359, 0.146775916, 0.048355623, 0.049236469, 
0.074249201, 0.042370443, 0.040626626, 0.094437822, 0.046528066, 
0.05148911, 0.060980887, 0.060188385, 0.077146076, 0.053584377, 
0.063219362, 0.050217884, 0.060380718, 0.077166513, NA, 0.417317819, 
NA, NA, 0.050967868, NA, NA, 0.171600774, 0.075110846, 0.407966882, 
NA, 0.317172879, 0.14913279, 0.181668808, NA, 0.209085025, NA, 
NA, 0.181146078, 0.194934388, 0.147458219, 0.20603389, 0.159845411, 
0.167280953, 0.184498482, NA, 0.116541941, 0.203738519, 0.165296042, 
0.188392641, 0.213356813, 0.163580836, 0.16583046, 0.278539249, 
0.176512754, 0.189747006, 0.127297963, 0.097622766, 0.14965216, 
0.138453154, 0.093268444, 0.194231674, 0.109519249, 0.080222972, 
0.107647036, 0.074088679, 0.080116949, 0.087413981, 0.135143153, 
0.080069624, 0.111665621, 0.07615619, 0.123522342, 0.111357589, 
0.291819884, 0.102793506, 0.129541771, 0.077439141, 0.211007708, 
0.112699582, 0.238495917, 0.048760198, 0.10311381, 0.058783217, 
0.187679402, 0.105958326, 0.098303641, 0.080843973, 0.052070696, 
0.119010333, 0.077476701, 0.131770602, 0.088461915, 0.072832336, 
0.036611459, 0.074172134, NA, 0.03982938, 0.166489651, 0.101680555, 
0.100558381, 0.073767248, 0.082808278, 0.119402936, 0.136595719, 
0.216845566, 0.296923823, 0.228383844, 0.162111224, 0.231735943, 
0.09593012, 0.13931631, 0.092081041, 0.343116293, 0.107501464, 
NA, 0.091976987, 0.121355731, NA, NA, 0.143166393, NA, 0.206475454, 
0.183337007, NA, 0.07489074, NA, 0.151679047, 0.18253156, 0.092401174, 
0.249826082, NA, NA, 0.388233583, 0.238975608, 0.165197158, 0.03402928, 
0.107258374, 0.135504625, 0.199937322, 0.386272593, 0.282663422, 
0.079703991, 0.084003722, 0.053736181, 0.065844789, 0.035722026, 
0.070159213, 0.045913757, 0.068252653, 0.092070417, 0.050934179, 
0.053299503, 0.07119216, 0.091180257, 0.081479255, 0.061368078, 
0.079272001, 0.041578686, 0.063021913, 0.044307119, 0.052951682
), Video3 = c(0.144167749, 0.053938585, 0.074156272, 0.068384241, 
0.257212592, 0.243452094, 0.072577209, 0.063810703, 0.147408183, 
0.059354697, 0.04634975, 0.07846023, 0.196462309, 0.099933835, 
0.145683333, 0.158305327, 0.105569594, 0.060838186, 0.102196312, 
0.057709436, 0.065818121, 0.066244457, 0.105116003, 0.054189254, 
0.205065965, 0.163002871, 0.180032663, 0.051182716, 0.102318964, 
0.245352358, 0.145898239, 0.186285454, 0.095095281, 0.156748828, 
0.15570742, 0.053803903, 0.033606179, 0.07365876, 0.05104256, 
NA, 0.053655528, 0.065751871, 0.082836706, 0.080429497, 0.039112058, 
0.06394257, 0.046803938, 0.092834672, 0.034565093, 0.048813169, 
0.095532111, NA, 0.212517948, 0.227250158, 0.183296206, 0.154160041, 
0.225198708, 0.271158885, 0.039183658, 0.199951527, NA, 0.177792295, 
0.110744145, 0.199889426, 0.106507314, 0.215298426, 0.099930914, 
NA, 0.040638466, 0.055748963, 0.0884863, 0.041390095, 0.043243241, 
0.13304215, 0.065264553, 0.064561766, 0.047361205, 0.069268582, 
0.061012224, 0.079270672, 0.037756581, 0.091278191, 0.07024436, 
0.061057298, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.087830029, 0.255102736, NA, 
NA, 0.447484104, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.593477276, NA, 0.18095392, 
0.192736027, 0.198110005, 0.17373631, 0.190351037, 0.183725822, 
0.201399389, 0.197716107, 0.182643112, 0.169019664, 0.184499611, 
0.15968721, 0.198214947, 0.138778453, 0.259120036, 0.254541772, 
NA, 0.138387786, 0.132525415, 0.095001906, 0.110843691, 0.157754136, 
0.099714141, 0.259360142, 0.108598563, 0.090730258, 0.08742319, 
0.076818785, NA, NA, 0.120915331, 0.112465074, 0.109784663, 0.071975707, 
0.236083514, 0.060273625, NA, NA, NA, 0.122126069, NA, 0.223049768, 
NA, 0.148602074, 0.15451306, 0.081655106, 0.08779288, 0.085110963, 
0.182273997, 0.079916129, NA, 0.07299758, 0.049128115, 0.101086955, 
NA, 0.370434594, 0.045494486, 0.05161485, 0.056470279, 0.075544203, 
0.074006203, 0.073745287, 0.066680245, 0.111868223, 0.128480808, 
0.115794281, 0.137204024, NA, NA, NA, 0.123755171, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 0.209945869, 0.158594182, 0.192175776, NA, NA, 0.084841772, 
0.037790634, 0.110958609, 0.14481606, NA, NA, 0.115507315, 0.008844521, 
NA, 0.039626847, NA, 0.140239324, NA, 0.147622419, 0.130914464, 
0.19425935, 0.029198683, 0.123614597, 0.122745111, NA, 0.087697701, 
0.37026571, NA, 0.21681181, 0.110354032, NA, 0.059406045, 0.063982092, 
0.050064775, 0.116552375, NA, NA, 0.106103895, 0.027066922, 0.083329503, 
0.061009608, 0.072162348, NA, 0.110920872, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.092201503
)), row.names = c(NA, -226L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking at the clustering within the three "Video" columns as an outcome variable then that need to be represented in a `long` format. I can show you an example. Be aware that non-convergence leads to erroneous estimates. Simply stated, they cannot be used at all. Failure to converge means that the algorithm within `lme4` cannot find reasonable estimates because there is not enough data on each level to do so. There is a lot of info on convergence if you google it.

```
df <- df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = 5:7)

df

# Converge ok
lmer(log(value) ~1 + (1|Day) + (1|ID),df)

# Day (random effect) explains 1.6 % of the variation
# ID (random effect) explains 38.2 % of the variation
```